# Github Action: Parse pylint score and fail test based on threshold

Tags: python, bash, github, github-actions

I am trying to setup CI on github action, I already have a working action shown bellow.  What it does is it run pylint, save the output to git env var and write a message to the pull request with it.  This works great.

However I need to check the pylint score and fail the action if it is bellow a certain threshold.  I already know that there is a `--fail-under` flag, however I don't want to use it, because it will skip writing the output to comment.  Is it possible for me to save the pylint score and check it later?  After the comment is already writen?  I currently use `--exit-zero` flag so pylint would pass and I can write the comment.

Here is what I currently have:

```
- name: Lint with pylint
      working-directory: ./
      run: |
        echo  '${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}'
        pip install pylint
        OUTPUT = $(pylint ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_updated }} ${{ steps.files.outputs.files_created }}  --exit-zero --jobs=0)
        SCORE = 0
        echo "Pylint finished with score: $SCORE"
        echo 'MESSAGE<<EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo  "$OUTPUT"  >> $GITHUB_ENV
        echo 'EOF' >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

How do I get score from pylint on this line: `SCORE = 0`?

And how do I fail the test afterward?

The output from pylint look like this:

```
************* Module src.server
src/server.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
src/server.py:5:0: W0401: Wildcard import src.endpoints (wildcard-import)
...
-----------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.18/10
```

Comment: why not use `pylint`'s `--fail-under`?

Comment: I won't be able to write a PR comment with the result before it fail

Comment: Sure you can. Capture the error code, write the PR comment, then exit the script with the error code. Note also that you can't write `VAR = VALUE` in the shell, you need to lose those spaces so you have `VAR=VALUE`.

Comment: Really?  Can you provide an example of how to do that in an answer?